# java private class member

Tags: java, class

I faced this code in a sockets tutorial. 
First we create an array and put instances of clientThread in it:

```
public class MultiThreadChatServer {
...
private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];
...
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == null) {
            (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
```

And here is the clientThread class(part of it):

```
class clientThread extends Thread {

  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final clientThread[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;

  public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
  }

  public void run() {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

    try {
      /*
       * Create input and output streams for this client.
       */
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      os.println("Enter your name.");
      String name = is.readLine().trim();
      os.println("Hello " + name
          + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line");
      for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
        if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
          threads[i].os.println("A new user"+name+"entered the chat room");
        }
      }
```

My problem is with the last line of code: threads[i].os.println(). 'os' is a private member, how is it possible we are accessing it outside it's own class or without a getter method?

Comment: The method run is a member of clientThread. Why shouldn't it be able to access the private member os on a clientThread instance?

Comment: @lakshman - there's no reflection in this and it's not needed.

Comment: It's in it's own class as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for `os` because an instance can access private members of other instances of the same class. Access control in Java is determined at the class level, not at the instance level. Scala, for example, has the modifier `private[this]` to mark a member as instance-level private.

Comment: Why don't people read the full question? It's called shadowing.

Comment: @Troubleshoot: I read the whole question... Care to explain your thoughts?

Comment: Does any body else confirm this answer? You can access private members of other objects if they are from the same class?

Comment: @PouriaP - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html `a class always has access to its own members`

Comment: It's not it's own members, it's accessing another instance's members

Comment: @PouriaP: but it's a member of the same class!

Comment: @Jordão public class MultiThreadChatServer {
...
private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount]; // the op is trying to access this field from the clientThread class

Comment: @Troubleshoot: it's not about the `threads` field, which is passed as a parameter to `clientThread`'s constructor.